# Javascript and HTML source code is shown in browser when source code path is provided as url

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am working on a web project where I am using .net as a developer platform and javascript and html for designing. Problem what I am facing is that whenever I am giving the js source code path as url (http://localhost/MyProject/js/globalize.min.js) then the entire code is displayed in the browser and whenever I am giving the .html path(http://localhost/PAPortLocal/Name/Detail.html/) then the browser is downloading that .html page.

Is there any thing I can do with the web.confic file to avoid this security issue

Comment: When you reference that is file from within your HTML, the browser still needs to download it!

Comment: This is how the internet works. The browser downloads the HTML, JS and CSS to render the page and when you type the specific URL you can see the code (https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-4c3a68124ec3c7e884cb392d5e0556b9.js) You can use minifying tools to scramble a bit the code, but the purpose for minifying is to reduce traffic and increase performance of your page, the code is still visible.